# Serve Django static files in kubernetes

Tags: django, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to host a Django project inside Kubernetes. But now am facing an issue to serve static files of Django. So I researched about it. In my researches found that storage objects are a better option like S3. Can I serve static files without using S3? I trying to serve using the Nginx server. I tried in different ways but I didn't get a solution.

Here is my deployment YAML. And I attached a volume for static files and media files. Can I possible serve static files and media files from that volume using Nginx

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: m3-mobiles-deployment
  labels:
    app: m3-mobiles

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: m3-mobiles
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: m3-mobiles
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: m3-mobiles-assets-vol
          hostPath:
            path: /home/docker/m3mobiles/assets
        - name: m3-mobiles-media-vol
          hostPath:
              path: /home/docker/m3mobiles/media
      containers:
        - name: m3-mobiles
          image: amjedsaleel/m3mobiles
          volumeMounts:
            - name: m3-mobiles-assets-vol
              mountPath: /app/assets
            - name: m3-mobiles-media-vol
              mountPath: /app/media
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          env:
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: secret-key
            - name: DEBUG
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: debug
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: db-name
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: db-user
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: db-password
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-config-map
                  key: postgres_db_url
            - name: DB_PORT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: db-port
            - name: TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: twilio-account-sid
            - name: TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: twilio_auth_token
            - name: VERIFICATION_SID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: verification-sid
            - name: RAZOR_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: razor-key-id
            - name: RAZOR_KEY_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: m3-mobiles-secret
                  key: razor-key-secrete

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: m3-mobiles-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: m3-mobiles
#  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8000
```

ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: m3-mobiles-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "m3mobiles.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: m3-mobiles-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Why not just use your cloud provider's storage solution? It's a best practice to avoid the use of `hostPath` when possible.

Comment: You could also use [Django's native static-file support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial06/) without a separate Nginx container.  And to reinforce @p10l's point, delete the `volumes:` block entirely: all of your application should be in the image, especially in Kubernetes it doesn't work to inject half of it from somewhere else.

Comment: Use whitenoise to sever static files from your wsgi runner

Comment: @Amjed any updates?

Comment: Now, I am using S3.

Comment: So, did you solved your issue?

Comment: No, I am not solved yet. Now I am loading a static file from S3 Bucket.

Comment: It's possible to serve static files with nginx, when configured as a sidecar. Some examples are available [here](https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2021/Mar/31/manage-static-k8s-django/) and [here](https://www.meanpug.com/django-on-kubernetes-as-concisely-as-possible/). Do you think it would work for you?